# Difference between using `dotnet ef migrations add` and VS Package Manager console's `Add-Migration`?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm facing a problem when trying to create a new code-first migration. When I use `dotnet ef migrations add <migration-name>`, I get

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)

However, if I use `Add-Migration <migration-name>` from the PM Console (or PowerShell) instead, the migration is created successfully.

I can live with this for now, but I'm curious as to what can cause this difference.

Comment: Have you tried running `dotnet` from PM console?

Comment: yes, it gives the same error.